# Sorting a vector of pairs first element increasing, second element decreasing

Tags: c++, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
#define pb push_back
#define ll long long
int main(void)
{
int n, q, w;
cin>>n;
vector< pair <int,int> > a;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin>>q>>w;
    a.push_back( make_pair(q,w) );
}
sort(a.begin(), a.end());
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cout<<a[i].first<<" "<<a[i].second<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

I need the vector to be sorted first element increasing and if there are multiple first elements with the same size the second element should be sorted decreasing.

Here's some examples which I have tried (also what output I want):

```
Input: 7
       1 1
       1 9
       1 3
       5 4
       3 2
       8 8
       5 1

Program output: 1 1
                1 3 
                1 9
                3 2
                5 1
                5 4
                8 8

Output I need: 1 9
               1 3
               1 1
               3 2
               5 4
               5 1
               8 8
```

Comment: You have included many unnecessary header files

Comment: Yeah i know that's the template i use

Comment: ok thanks for the help, do you know the answer to my queastion?

Answer (score 4):

`std::sort` can be passed a comparator to be used to compare elements. Using `std::tie` is a convenient way of comparing tuples:

```
std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(),[](const auto& a,const auto& b){
    return std::tie(a.first,b.second) < std::tie(b.first,a.second);
});
```

Note how the `second` elements of the pairs are swapped to get them in decreasing order.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to customize the comparator function of the `sort`function.
This can be implemented with a lambda function.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>


int main() {
    int n, q, w;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> a;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> q >> w;
        a.push_back ({q, w});
    }
    auto fsort = [] (const std::pair<int,int>& a, const std::pair<int,int>& b) {
        if (a.first != b.first) return a.first < b.first;
        return a.second > b.second;
    };
    std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), fsort);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cout << a[i].first << " " << a[i].second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```